# How to get Distinct values using RestHighLevelClient in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, distinct, elasticsearch-query, resthighlevelclient

I saw the post here where you guys gave solution for the link given below.
[ElasticSearch Java API to get distinct values from the Query Builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138501/elasticsearch-java-api-to-get-distinct-values-from-the-query-builders)

Is there any way to achieve distinct emails using `org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient`?
Could you please help me on this, i tried so many ways but could not able to solve it. But I am able to achieve the same in SQL Workbench and the equivalent json query is given below using Kibana translator.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT email_client.keyword
FROM email_reference;
```

Equivalent Elasticsearch query given below:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["email_client.keyword"],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": "email_client.keyword",
  "aggregations": {
    "email_client.keyword": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email_client.keyword",
        "size": 200,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So now i wanted form this JSON query using RestHighLevelClient, I have tried but the problem is prepareSearch() is not there in RestHighLevelClient is there any other to achieve using RestHighLevelClient?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with the RestHighLevelClient:

```
        MultiSearchRequest multiRequest = new MultiSearchRequest();
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.size(0); // return only aggregation results
        searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("label_agg").field("email_client.keyword").size(200));
        searchRequest.indices("email_reference"); // index name
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        multiRequest.add(searchRequest);
        MultiSearchResponse response = restHighLevelClient.msearch(multiRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

For elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client with version 7.11.2, below example worked for me. You need to set an aggregation for a field with keyword.

```java
    private List<String> queryForDistinctMetadata(String aggregationKey, String field) throws IOException {

        var aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .terms(aggregationKey)
                .field(field);

        var searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
                .aggregation(aggregationBuilder)
                .size(0);

        var searchRequest = new SearchRequest()
                .indices("<your index here>")
                .source(searchSourceBuilder);

        var response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        var aggregation = (ParsedStringTerms) response.getAggregations().get(aggregationKey);

        return aggregation.getBuckets()
                .parallelStream()
                .map(Terms.Bucket::getKeyAsString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```